# Adding session attributes in Python for Alexa skills

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have 3 slots (`account`, `dollar_value`, `recipient_first`) within my intent schema for an Alexa skill and I want to save whatever slots are provided by the speaker in the session Attributes.

I am using the following methods to set session attributes:

```
def create_dollar_value_attribute(dollar_value):
    return {"dollar_value": dollar_value}

def create_account_attribute(account):
    return {"account": account}

def create_recipient_first_attribute(recipient_first):
    return {"recipient_first": recipient_first}
```

However, as you may guess, if I want to save more than one slot as data in `sessionAttributes`, the `sessionAttributes` is overwritten as in the following case:

```
session_attributes = {}
if session.get('attributes', {}) and "recipient_first" not in session.get('attributes', {}):
        recipient_first = intent['slots']['recipient_first']['value']
        session_attributes = create_recipient_first_attribute(recipient_first)


if session.get('attributes', {}) and "dollar_value" not in session.get('attributes', {}):
        dollar_value = intent['slots']['dollar_value']['value']
        session_attributes = create_dollar_value_attribute(dollar_value)
```

The JSON response from my lambda function for a speech input in which two slots (`dollar_value` and `recipient_first`) were provided is as follows (my guess is that `the create_dollar_value_attribute` method in the second if statement is overwriting the first):

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "text": "Some text output"
    },
    "card": {
      "content": "SessionSpeechlet - Some text output",
      "title": "SessionSpeechlet - Send Money",
      "type": "Simple"
    },
    "reprompt": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "PlainText"
      }
    },
    "shouldEndSession": false
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {
    "dollar_value": "30"
  }
}
```

The correct response for `sessionAttributes` should be:

```
"sessionAttributes": {
    "dollar_value": "30",
    "recipient_first": "Some Name"
  },
```

How do I create this response? Is there a better way to add values to `sessionAttributes` in the JSON response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to add `sessionAttributes` with Python in my opinion seems to be by using a dictionary. For example, if you want to store some of the slots for future in the session attributes:

```
session['attributes']['slotKey'] = intent['slots']['slotKey']['value']
```

Next, you can just pass it on to the build response method:

```
buildResponse(session['attributes'], buildSpeechletResponse(title, output, reprompt, should_end_session))
```

The implementation in this case:

```
def buildSpeechletResponse(title, output, reprompt_text, should_end_session):
return {
    'outputSpeech': {
        'type': 'PlainText',
        'text': output
    },
    'card': {
        'type': 'Simple',
        'title': "SessionSpeechlet - " + title,
        'content': "SessionSpeechlet - " + output
    },
    'reprompt': {
        'outputSpeech': {
            'type': 'PlainText',
            'text': reprompt_text
        }
    },
    'shouldEndSession': should_end_session
    }


def buildResponse(session_attributes, speechlet_response):
    return {
        'version': '1.0',
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'response': speechlet_response
    }
```

This creates the sessionAttributes in the recommended way in the Lambda response JSON.

Also just adding a new sessionAttribute doesn't overwrite the last one if it doesn't exist. It will just create a new key-value pair.

Do note, that this may work well in the service simulator but may return a key attribute error when testing on an actual Amazon Echo. According to this [post](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/51853/skill-works-perfectly-in-service-simulator-but-ech.html),

On Service Simulator, sessions starts with Session:{ ... Attributes:{}, ... }
When sessions start on the Echo, Session does not have an Attributes key at all.

The way I worked around this was to just manually create it in the lambda handler whenever a new session is created:

```
 if event['session']['new']:
    event['session']['attributes'] = {}
    onSessionStarted( {'requestId': event['request']['requestId'] }, event['session'])
if event['request']['type'] == 'IntentRequest':
    return onIntent(event['request'], event['session'])
```

Comment: I don't have attributes in `event['session']` however I don't understand how instantiating this `event['session']['attributes'] = {}` will fix it? How will alexa/lambda know? What does the `onSessionStarted` function do?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to define the session_attributes.

```
session_attributes = {}
```

Then instead of using

```
session_attributes = create_recipient_first_attribute(recipient_first)
```

You should use

`session_attributes.update(create_recipient_first_attribute(recipient_first))`.

The problem you are facing is because you are reassigning the session_attributes. Instead of this, you should just update the session_attributes.

So your final code will become:

```
session_attributes = {}
if session.get('attributes', {}) and "recipient_first" not in session.get('attributes', {}):
    recipient_first = intent['slots']['recipient_first']['value']
    session_attributes.update(create_recipient_first_attribute(recipient_first))
if session.get('attributes', {}) and "dollar_value" not in session.get('attributes', {}):
    dollar_value = intent['slots']['dollar_value']['value']
    session_attributes.update(create_dollar_value_attribute(dollar_value))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ASK SDK for Python](https://github.com/alexa-labs/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python) provides an [attribute manager](https://alexa-skills-kit-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ATTRIBUTES.html), to manage request/session/persistence level attributes in the skill. You can look at the [color picker sample](https://github.com/alexa-labs/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/tree/master/samples/ColorPicker), to see how to use these attributes in skill development.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below:

```
account = intent['slots']['account']['value'] 
dollar_value = intent['slots']['dollar_value']['value'] 
recipient_first = intent['slots']['recipient_first']['value']  

# put your data in a dictionary
attributes = { 
    'account':account, 
    'dollar_value':dollar_value, 
    'recipient_first':recipient_first
}
```

Put the ***attributes*** dictionary in ***'sessionAttributes'*** in your response. You should get it back in ***'sessionAttributes'*** once Alexa replies to you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet will also prevent overwriting the session attributes:

```
session_attributes = session.get('attributes', {})

if "recipient_first" not in session_attributes:
    session_attributes['recipient_first'] = intent['slots']['recipient_first']['value']

if "dollar_value" not in session_attributes:
    session_attributes['dollar_value'] =  = intent['slots']['dollar_value']['value']
```