# Recall a session variable in Python for an Alexa skill

Tags: python-2.7, alexa-skills-kit

So I've read this post: [Adding session attributes in Python for Alexa skills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992487/adding-session-attributes-in-python-for-alexa-skills) and it solved my problems of being able to store multiple session variables.

However, now my issue is recalling these session variable in another function.  Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
speech_output = "Your invoice for " + session['attributes']['invoiceAmount'] + \
                " dollars."
```

I have also tried this sort of code to set a local variable to the session variable:

```
invoice_amount = int(session['attributes']['invoiceAmount'])
```

What am I doing wrong?  I have never programmed in Python before so I'm kind of just teaching myself by looking at Amazon's Favorite Color example code and adapting it to my needs.  I actually have three session variables, but obviously if I can get one of them to work, I can figure out the other.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really sorry, I finally figured out the error.  My session variables were storing integers, however I was trying to concatenate those integers with text.  I didn't realize that I needed to first convert them to a string.  I converted to a string and that solved all of my problems.

Comment: Can you delete the question?

Comment: It said that I shouldn't delete the question, when I clicked delete.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem involves the scope of the `session` variable.

The following code is the intent invocation from the color expert skill.
As you can see in line 1 the variable `session` is defined as an argument.  On line 12 that variable is passed to the function `set_color_in_session(intent,session)`.

```
def on_intent(intent_request, session): # <-------------
    """ Called when the user specifies an intent for this skill """

    print("on_intent requestId=" + intent_request['requestId'] +
          ", sessionId=" + session['sessionId'])

    intent = intent_request['intent']
    intent_name = intent_request['intent']['name']

    # Dispatch to your skill's intent handlers
    if intent_name == "MyColorIsIntent":
        return set_color_in_session(intent, session) # <-------------
    elif intent_name == "WhatsMyColorIntent":
        return get_color_from_session(intent, session) # <-------------
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.HelpIntent":
        return get_welcome_response()
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid intent")
```

From the information provided I believe you defined your own functions to be fired by custom intents and most likely forgot to pass the `session` variable to those functions.  Again, the variable `session` will only exist inside your function if it is passed in as an argument.  Take for example the function `def get_color_from_session(intent, session):`.  Because `session` is passed in as an argument it is available inside this function on line 6, `favorite_color = session['attributes']['favoriteColor']`.

If you do not pass in the variable `session` you will be referencing a local variable named `session` that likely does not exist.

```
def get_color_from_session(intent, session):
    session_attributes = {}
    reprompt_text = None

    if "favoriteColor" in session.get('attributes', {}):
        favorite_color = session['attributes']['favoriteColor'] #<-------------
        speech_output = "Your favorite color is " + favorite_color + \
                        ". Goodbye."
        should_end_session = True
    else:
        speech_output = "I'm not sure what your favorite color is. " \
                        "You can say, my favorite color is red."
        should_end_session = False

    # Setting reprompt_text to None signifies that we do not want to reprompt
    # the user. If the user does not respond or says something that is not
    # understood, the session will end.
    return build_response(session_attributes, build_speechlet_response(
        intent['name'], speech_output, reprompt_text, should_end_session))
```

Comment: I didn't know that, but I checked my code and I am indeed passing thru the session variable into each function thru the on_intent function as I just cut and pasted the original code and changed the names of the intents and functions.

However, that other article that I linked to above has the code at the end about manually creating a lambda handler.  I have no idea where I am supposed to place that code.  Could that be the issue?